# How to add a widget in Android 4.2 emulator?

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-widget

I recently downloaded Android SDK and running Android 4.2 on the emulator. However, I don't see any option to add widget on my home screen. (I can't even add default widget).

I remember on Android 2.2, a long press on screen would pop up a context menu which will give an option to add a widget. I don't find any option in the new emulator.

How to add a widget in Android 4.2 emulator?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to open the applications screen, in it to scroll right until you get to the widgets section. from there pull the widget that you want and add it to the desired desktop.

Comment: For me there is no scrolling right in the applications screen :(

Comment: @IARI, in the new device you should press a long press on the home screen, and you will see three option (Wallpapers, Widgets and Settings.)

Answer (score 0):

For LD player there is no such menu or long press. Gotta install a launcher and do it that way. Seems like they forgot to add this basic feature when they built that emulator.