# How to add an app widget on the Android SDK emulator home screen?

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-widget

I'm using Nexus 4 as the emulator. Every time I long click on my emulator's home screen, this happens:

[image: http://oi41.tinypic.com/fmsvph.jpg]

How can I add an app widget there?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to add widget in android emulator 4.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15148539/how-to-add-widget-in-android-emulator-4-2)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Widget has been integrated into the app list. Go to app list, then scroll to the right, or click the "Widgets" tab. To add the widget, long-click the widget and put it on home screen.